# check multiple input values with javascript and marking multiple input boxes on 1 check

Tags: javascript, jquery

I expected the following function to apply a red border to BOTH the input field with id 'name', AS the input field with the id 'email'. (when the user leaves all input-fields empty)

However, the script only applies the red border to the input-field with id 'name', and leaves the field with id 'email' untouched.

```
            function checkform() {
                if ( name() && mail() ) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            function name() {
                if (document.getElementById("name").value == "") {
                    $("#name").css("border", "1px solid red");
                    return false;
                } else { 
                    return true; 
                }
            }

            function mail() {
                if (document.getElementById("email").value == "") {
                    $("#email").css("border", "1px solid red");
                    return false;
                } else { 
                    return true; 
                }
           }
```

It seems like the return false in the sub-function 'name()' somehow 'kills' the entire code, and stops 'mail()' from every being run.

**Update**:
If I switch the function-names in the 2nd line only the input-field with id 'email' gets a red border (if user leaves all input-fields empty).
Then the field with id 'name' remains untouched.

(Sorry for using javascript and jquery at the same time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If statement runs the conditions one by one until it is sure that they don't fulfill the condition. In your case if `name()` is false it will never run the conditions after it. In your case you can try using something like:

```
function checkform() {
   var isValid = name();
   isValid = mail() && isValid;
   return isValid;
}
```

However I recommend you to write a generic function that will check if some input given as parameter is empty.

Also there is quite nice jQuery plugin that might help you with your task: http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, somehow Sushant led me to the answer (a nano-second sooner).

Comment: No problem, however keep in mind that with  "!name() && !mail()" you might have an issue where your script thinks the form is valid but in fact the name is valid and the mail is not, i.e: (false && !mail())

Comment: DAMN, that is ExAcTLy what's happening now. I have to think this through harder.

Answer (score 0):

The return false statement in the name function is short-circuiting the statement inside the if condition. 
While evaluating if( name() && mail() ), name() returns false and since AND with false always gives false, the statement is short-circuited and the mail() function is never called.

Comment: Ok, I'll try !name() && !mail() and 'swap' what is returned.